# Add a number of days to SAS datetime format

Tags: sas, dataset, radix, enterprise-guide

I need help with SAS datetime format. 
Dataset(including desired column exp_dt):

```
    datetime            valid           exp_dt
4OCT2017:13.00.00         1         5OCT2017:13.00.00   
4OCT2017:15.20.00         7         11OCT2017:15.20.00
6OCT2017:08.00.00         30        5NOV2017:08.00.00
```

So, I need to add valid values (number of days) to datetime.
I've just started with SAS Base and I am not sure if any other datetime format is acceptable. 
I've tried with this, but not sure if even going in right direction:

```
PlannedSchedTime = datetime ;
Postunit = 'DAY' ;
postval = valid ;
exp_dt = put(intnx(Postunit,PlannedSchedTime,postval,'same'),datetime20.);
put exp_dt= ;
run;
```

Also, I'm working on project in SAS Enterprise Guide, so maybe there is easier way through the GUI tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a code sample that will print your desired result. Like the other answer states, `DTDAY` will tell SAS to add days when the base value is a datetime instead of a date.

```
data datetimes;
    informat datetime anydtdtm. valid best12.;
    format datetime datetime20.;
    input datetime valid;
    cards;
4OCT2017:13.00.00 1
4OCT2017:15.20.00 7
6OCT2017:08.00.00 30
;
run;

data datetimes_added;
    set datetimes;
    format exp_dt datetime20.;
    exp_dt = intnx('DTDAY',datetime,valid,'SAME');
    put exp_dt = ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely on the right path! Because you are dealing with `datetime` values, replace `DAY` by `dtDAY`.

If you don't want `exp_dt`  to be a character column, don't use the `put` function but rather a format (e.g. `format exp_dt2 datetime20.;`).

Comment: In SAS, `datetime` is just number of seconds since `1960-01-01 00:00:00` displayed in a human-readable format. That's why adding `24*60*60*valid` would also work - I'm not sure how daylight savings time would affect the result though.

Comment: Datetime values don't have any notion of daylight savings time, so the simple math you give there would work for the example in the question. I prefer the intnx function though because it seems cleaner and I find it easier to interpret.